# Doctrine, use resultset to map DTO

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, resultset, dto

I want to do something a bit tricky using doctrine, native sql, resultSet and DTO. I need some help.

This is an exemple, my real entities are more complexe than here.

Let's say, I have two entity contact1 and contact2, they are similar, as they have a few column in common (let's say first_name, lastname, and email), but otherwise they are fully different.

I created a DTO ContactDTO, which will have the following property:

- id
- type (contact1 or contact2)
- firstname
- lastname
- email

I have a sql request to fetch all the data using union, for example :

```
SELECT * FROM (
   (SELECT c1.id, 'contact1' as type, c1.firstname, c1.lastname, c1.email from contact1)
   UNION
   (SELECT c2.id, 'contact2' as type, c2.firstname, c2.lastname, c2.email from contact2)
) as contact order by lastname, firstname
limit 50
```

(In my real case I have a few other subquery, grouping and where clause)

Is it possible using doctrine and result set to map my sql query directly into the contactDTO ?

I am using Symfony 5.4 (PHP 8.1), and doctrine/orm version 2.13.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but I think this does what you want https://dev.to/jszutkowski/fast-way-to-create-dto-using-doctrine-2dlf

Comment: Yes I want to use dto the same way doctrine use them. But in most exemple I saw they use DQL to generate the DTO, which I cannot use because I need UNION operator, which DQL cannot manipulate.